# react, forms: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have very simple structure here. I have an input and textarea. I want to manage input/textarea values in state. Also I want to validate textarea field (max 140 characters). I make simple if for that.

And now, when I type something in first input, I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at App.render (App.jsx:44) (...)

I have no idea why I have this error. I even don't do anything on my textarea field yet...

code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    formValues: {
      title: "",
      description: ""
    }
  };

  titleValueChangeHandler = e => this.setState({ formValues: { title: e.target.value } });


  descriptionValueChangeHandler = e => {
    if (this.state.formValues.description.length === 140) return;
    this.setState({ formValues: { description: e.target.value } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.titleValueChangeHandler}
          value={this.state.formValues.title}
        />
        <textarea
          onChange={this.descriptionValueChangeHandler}
          value={this.state.formValues.description}
        />
        <p>{this.state.formValues.description.length}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/kw6pnxwv0v

Comment: i have this problem in react, i am not sure of the root cause, but as a work around you can use `(this.state.formValues.description||'')` to keep it from crashing, since it safe to assume a default value of empty string. this is how i've always worked around this particular problem. if you do find the root cause, please share here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you rewrite state in eventHandler.

You need to use prevState for save prev state of object:

> titleValueChangeHandler = e => this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, formValues: { title: e.target.value, description: prevState.formValues.description }}));

And for closure refactor like this:

```
titleValueChangeHandler = e => {
const newValue = e.target.value
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, formValues: { title: newValue , description: prevState.formValues.description }}));
}
```